# Why do i get an error comparing NSString's? (-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSMutableArray (_theListOfAllQuestions)` that I am populating with numbers from a file. Then I compared the objects in that array with `qNr (NSString)` and I got error. I even casted the array to another `NSString`, `_checkQuestions`, just to be sure I am comparing `NSStrings`. I tested using item to compare also.

```
-(void)read_A_Question:(NSString *)qNr {
NSLog(@"read_A_Question: %@", qNr);
int counter = 0;
for (NSString *item in _theListOfAllQuestions) {
    NSLog(@"item: %@", item);
    _checkQuestions = _theListOfAllQuestions[counter]; //_checkQuestion = NSString
    NSLog(@"_checkQuestions: %@", _checkQuestions);
    if ([_checkQuestions isEqualToString:qNr]) {
        NSLog(@">>HIT<<");
        exit(0);   //Just for the testing
    }
    counter++;
 }
```

When running this code i get the following `NSLog`:

```
read_A_Question: 421
item: 1193
_checkQuestions: 1193
```

...and error:

> -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9246d80
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber
>   isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9246d80'

I do believe that I still comparing `NSString` with a number of some sort but to me it looks like I am comparing `NSString` vs. `NSString`?

I could really need some help here to 1) understand the problem, 2)solve the problem?

Comment: Well then `_checkQuestions`, in at least one case, is an `NSNumber` and not an `NSString`. What exactly is in `_theListOfAllQuestions`? And how is that being populated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace this line

```
if ([_checkQuestions isEqualToString:qNr])
```

with

```
 if ([[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_checkQuestions] isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",qNr]])
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: There is no need for `stringWithFormat` as `NSNumber` already has a property `-stringValue` that returns the number as a string.

Comment: @yulz I dont know datatype of _checkQuestions and there is no harm in using stringWithFormat..

Comment: @Praatek, that made it THANKS.

Comment: Appreciate that @Prateek :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your `_theListOfAllQuestions` array has `NSNumber` objects and not `NSString` objects. So you cant use `isEqualToString` directly.

Try this,

```
for (NSString *item in _theListOfAllQuestions) {
    NSLog(@"item: %@", item);
    _checkQuestions = _theListOfAllQuestions[counter]; //_checkQuestion = NSString
    NSLog(@"_checkQuestions: %@", _checkQuestions);
    if ([[_checkQuestions stringValue] isEqualToString:qNr]) {
        NSLog(@">>HIT<<");
        exit(0);   //Just for the testing
    }
    counter++;
 }
```

Comment: ABC, tried this also earlier and got "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'stringValue'"

Comment: That is because you should declare `_checkQuestions` as NSNumber and not NSSString. Your array has NSNumbers and not string. Usage of `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_checkQuestions]` is not recommended in this case. That will give unexpected results later.

Comment: Set _checkQuestions to `NSNumber`. You can either type cast it `[(NSNumber *)_checkQuestions stringValue]` in your if statement or change the type where you have declared _checkQuestions to NSNumber

Comment: I tried both of the above suggestions and get no error but no if-hit either? ...as i get with the suggestion from Prateek.

Comment: @PeterK, It is upto you to decide whether you want to do it in the proper way or do it in a way which can break your code later. Usage of `[NSString stringWithFormat:` got a different purpose. There is a reason why apple has added `stringValue` in `NSNumber` class for these type of conversions.

Comment: @ABC, i have continued to test and found a typo i did, which means that your suggestion did work, my embarrassing mistake. You are correct, thanks a lot :-)  ...now i learned something very useful! +1